# Why in C++, I don't need to dereference a pointer to an array in order to access items in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm currently learning pointer. And when I create a pointer to an array with int type, I found that I can directly index the pointer without deferencing the pointer and the compiler still output exact items in my array. I do not understand why this works and why we don't need to first deference the pointer.

Code that without dereference

```
int arraySize = 5;
int* theArray = new int[arraySize];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    theArray[i] = i;
}

for (int i = 0; I < 5; i++)
{
    std::cout << theArray[i] << std::endl;
}
```

And this gives me the output

[Output without derefercing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlTvR.png)

However, when I wrote like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    (*theArray)[i] = i;
}
```

My compiler says that: Error: expression must have pointer-to-object type. (I'm using Visual Studio 2013.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Code that without dereference
>
> ```
> [ code ]
> ```

That's incorrect. You are most certainly dereferencing your pointer:

```
 theArray[i] = i;
```

That's a pointer dereference. The `[]` operator dereferences the pointer. This is equivalent to:

```
 *(theArray+i) = i;
```

As you know, adding or subtracting a value to a pointer advances or decrements the pointer, producing a new pointer value, and then the pointer gets dereferenced.

Also:

```
 *p = q;
```

is equivalent to

```
 p[0] = q;
```

The `[]` operator is just a shorthand for adding an offset to a pointer, and dereferencing the resulting pointer with the `*` operator. The end result is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. `*(theArray+i) = i;` and  `*p = q;` == `p[0] = q;` made it all come together for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand why this works and why we don't need to first deference the pointer.

The first version is correct:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    theArray[i] = i;
}
```

because `theArray[i]` is actually `*(theArray + i)` - essentially pointer arithmetic is equivalent to array index.

On the other hand, the 2nd version is incorrect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    (*theArray)[i] = i;
}
```

That's because `(*theArray)[i]` is actually pointer to array (not the array itself), and so it caused a type mismatch as the compiler already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A few other answers correctly say that `*(theArray + i)` is equivalent to `theArray[i]`.  But the point I think you missed when learning is that unlike most objects a pointer to an array is not a pointer to the array that is then dereferenced, and then array logic, it is only a pointer to the first ***element*** of the array.  That's why this:

```
int *myIntPointer = new int[5];
```

is NEARLY the same as this:

```
int myIntArray[5];  // "True" array on the stack
```

But you can also point it at something else:

```
int myInt = 10;
delete [] myIntPointer;
myIntPointer = &myInt;
```

It's also why doing the follow CAN give a compiler warning, but can also work (depends on the compiler):

```
myIntPointer = myIntArray; // Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't, compiler dependent
```

That's because allocating an array with `new int[size]` returns a *pointer to an int* not a pointer to an "array" type.

It's a weird corner case of C/C++ that arrays and pointers interact this way.  You also run into it if you try and pass one of the "true" arrays into a function.

Comment: `myIntPointer = myIntArray` is not compiler-dependent

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure, since you get issues trying to pass into functions when you treat the two the same, though they're not.  But it might be a "Widening" conversion and thus be OK.  Thought it better to qualify it.  But thanks for the info.  It's just something I virtually never do.  STL if I have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

`theArray[i]` literally corresponds to `*(theArray + i)` so it already dereferences the pointer.

Indeed when you try to call `operator[]` on `*theArray` it yields you an error because it expects a pointer, not a real object.

Comment: But we can use the operator[] on an actual array object. So when I deference the pointer, what I get is an actual array, then why the operator[] won't work? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No, you are using `operator[]` on a `int*` object, not an array nor a pointer to an array. The fact that `theArray` points to 5 contiguous `int` is irrelevant for the semantics of the pointer. `theArray` is a pointer to `int`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking the wrong question for your misunderstanding — you should be asking why you can write

```
int* theArray = new int[arraySize];
```

In c++, array types are not like other types, and have a number of special cases and rules that make them behave differently from other types. In particular, `new T[N]` does not return a "pointer to an `N`-long array of `T`", it returns a "pointer to `T`". (specifically, to the first element of the newly created array)

For a more mindboggling example of this, observe:

```
typedef int T[5];
T* p = new T; // this does not compile
int* q = new T; // this does compile
```